Can a Turing Machine decide if a language is regular, in general?
Can a Turing machine decide/recognize if a given language is regular, in general?
$
REG_{TM}=\{\langle M\rangle|\langle M\rangle \text{ is a TM and }L(M) \text{ is regular}\}
$
I'm pretty confident that $REG_{TM}$ is not decidable/recursive, due to Rice's Theorem.
However, is it recursively enumerable? I know the pumping lemma can be used to determine if a language is not regular (and I am also curious whether that can be formalized into a TM), but is there a way to determine given a TM if a language is regular? I wonder if there's some way to try to construct a finite automata

Given any machine $M_1,$ let $M_2$ accept a string  $1111\dots1$ of length $p$ prime if $M_1,$ with input $0,$ does not halt by step $p.$ Then solving whether $M_2$ accepts a regular language is the same as answer the halting problem for $M_1.$

The pumping lemma can only prove a language is irregular, really. If you could use it, you could maybe use it to enumerate the complement of this set, but that seems unlikely, because such a decider would have to read its input machine and make a lot of inferences about it to apply the pumping lemma. I don't have an immediate proof of that, though

Also discussed here though the part about recursive enumerability is a bit terse.

Suppose $R$ is the set of maps $f : \mathsf{String} → \mathbb S_\bullet$ recognizing regular languages. I.E, the language recognized by a machine $M$ is regular if and only if it realizes an element of $R$.
The empty language is regular, which corresponds to the always divergent map. However, this is a finite sub-function of every map $\mathsf{String} → \mathbb S_\bullet$. So by the Rice-Shapiro theorem, if $R$ is RE, it must contain every such map (i.e. every recognizable language). But it doesn't, so $R$ must not be RE.
Intuitively, since the empty language is recognized by machines $M$ that always diverge (and we cannot reliably detect such machines by examining their implementation), the recognizer for $R$ must accept without any positive information about what $M$ actually accepts. And it can only do that by accepting every $M$.
